# Cannot POST /index.php

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I am new to php and I'm trying to get a contact form to send to my email. Every time I click the submit button, it redirects me to a page that says 'Cannot POST /index.php'. I have tried running it from localhost and deployed it to heroku, and still get the same error. The html and php files are in the same folder.

The console states the following error: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'.

The HTML code for the form is

```
<form name="sentMessage" role="form" id="contactForm" novalidate name="contactform" method="post" action="index.php">
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label for="first_name">Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label for="telephone">Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="telephone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label for="comments">Message:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="send-email">Send Message</button>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <?php echo $result; ?>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The PHP file is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'example@bootstrapbay.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if (!$_POST['telephone']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your telephone number';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in      touch</div>';
 } else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
}
}
    }
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let's test. In the HTML set the form `method="get"` and at the top of `index.php` put `echo 'this is index.php'; exit;` Now when you submit the form, do you see the message you echoed printed to the screen?

Comment: it downloads my index.php file when i do this

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't answer my question and I'm not sure what you mean by "it downloads my index.php".  Did you follow my test? So you see the message *"this is index.php"* printed on screen when you set `method="get"` in the HTML and submit the form?

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the name for your submit button since you are checking for it in the PHP.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

Therfore add it as follows:

```
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="send-email">Send Message</button>
```

also you need to check that the php is in the index.php that you are directing the form to send the data to.

also i think this is a typo (probably a copy / paste typo)

```
 if (!$_POST['telephone']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your telephone number';
```

should that be

```
  if (!$_POST['telephone']) {
        $errTelephone = 'Please enter your telephone number';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I set the name to the submit button and changed it to $errTelephone with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by 'check that the php is in the index.php that you are directing the form to send the data to'.

Comment: if you are directing the form to a page that does not include the specified php then you will not be able to process the form data - if this page is the index.php then you don't really need to specify the action of the form since it will post to itself and if the submit is set will process that. Incidentally I would probably wrap your $result in an isset() as well.

Comment: would probably suggest setting the form action to a dedicated php page eg: contact.php. If the above php is in the index.php and the html is in a different page (eg:somePage.html) then the brwoser will default to rendering the index.php as the standard home page - causing a problem since it may not have proper HTML declaations or code structure.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your POST HTTP Handler is disable / not working on your server , if its runs on your localhost, i think you should contact to server administrator or find on server control panel to enable it